# failed to delete the start_date with django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to delete the data between start_date and_date using django.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Porfolio.objects.filter(portfolio_id=portfolio_id, date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date).delete()
```

Problem:
whatever the start and end_date I am using, the start_date is not deleted while all the period afterward is deleted until end_date. and I am sure that in all cases I tested I have data in the start_date to delete. \

date is defined as date = models.DateField(). I use the format 'year-month-day' as a string in input (expl: start_date='2022-01-01'). No hours, minutes or timezones.\

Could not figure out why I am getting this behaviour.

Comment: There's also the [`range` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#range) which you can use. Is `date` actually a datetime field? Are `start_date` and `end_date` timezone aware?

Comment: can you give us more information about TZ or something?

Comment: date is defined as date = models.DateField(). I use the format 'year-month-day'  as a string in input.  No hours, minutes or timezones. I will add this in the question.

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74300490/17562044) please provide some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup and [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) objects together as stated by [@AbdulAzizBarkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299891/failed-to-delete-the-start-date-with-django-queryset#comment131173869_74299891) in the above comment so:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

Porfolio.objects.filter(Q(portfolio_id=portfolio_id) & Q(date__range=(start_date,end_date))).delete()
```

It will only work correctly if `date` is `DateField` not `DateTimeField` according to docs.